# Solaris equivalent for depth/prune?

Tags: find, solaris

I am trying to find some files inside a directory. By default, the find `command` is searching the directory which I have specified and it's sub directories.

I tried to use `depth/maxdepth` and `prune`, but nothing helped to overcome this. Can somebody point out the right way to use depth/prune in Solaris?

My code looks like this:

```
find file_path -depth 1 -name '*.log'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
find: bad option 1
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

Answer (score 16):

You're confusing two unrelated options that have vaguely similar names:

- `-depth` doesn't take any argument. If present, it tells `find` to process the contents of a directory before processing the directory itself.
- `-maxdepth N` (where N is an integer) limits the recursion to N levels of subdirectories.

The `-maxdepth` option is an extension found in some versions of `find`, but not Solaris's. There's a trick to using only standard options to `find` to process a directory without recursing: use `-prune` on subdirectories, but exclude the toplevel directory. Since the only way to match the toplevel directory is by name, arrange for the name to be `.` (which will never be the name of a subdirectory).

```
find /directory/to/traverse/. -name . -o \
                              -type d -prune -o \
                              -name '*.log' -print
```

Comment: I was facing this very problem, and this solution helped. I spent a day trying to find a solution to getting this to work. Grrr, Solaris.

Comment: Do you see any issue using sed to remove the /./ find ${directory}/sh/. -name . -o -type d -prune -o -print | sed 's/\/\.\//\//'

Comment: @EthanPost You can do that, but find implementations without `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` are a vanishing breed. If your find has `-maxdepth`, use `find /directory/to/traverse -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.log'`

Comment: @Gilles Just takes one to break you when you are building a framework that may need to run in just such a circumstance! That market may be my bread and butter someday! Thanks for the help.