# Arg list too long error while using find

Tags: shell-script, solaris

I have the `find` command as follows:

```
find /jobs/logs/* -prune -name '*.log' -type f -mtime +1 |
    while read LOGFILE
    do
        echo $LOGFILE
    done
```

This is failing due to the following error:

```
/usr/bin/find: arg list too long
```

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

(This is a continuation of [my previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18321/solaris-equivalent-for-depth-prune).)

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your `find` command to:

```
find /jobs/logs/. ! -name . -prune -name '*.log' -type f -mtime +1
```

This tells `find` to exclude the `.` directory and prune all the rest, so that it doesn't descend further.

Take a look at this page for more information: [Limit the search to the current directory portably](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/find/#limitcurrentdir)

Answer (score 4):

Let `find` to the directory traversal, that's its job! Building on my [previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18321/solaris-equivalent-for-depth-prune/18356#18356):

```
find /jobs/logs/. -name . -o -type d -prune -o
                  -type f -mtime +1 -exec sh -c 'echo "$0"' {} \;
```

Incidentally, note that I used `-exec` to make `find` invoke a command — that's what it's for.

Also, note that `read LOGFILE` does *not* read a line of input: it strips leading whitespace and interprets backslashes. A reliable way to read a line is `IFS= read -r LOGFILE`.