# Find and remove many files by specific content

Tags: grep, find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arg list too long error while using find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18327/arg-list-too-long-error-while-using-find)

I try to find many files in many folders with specific content, and delete them.

```
find dir.*/* -exec grep -l "content" {} \; | xargs rm -f
```

And I get following message:

```
-bash: /bin/find: Argument list too long
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why find dir.*/* instead of find dir.*? Is it intentional? Do you want to ommit dotflles/dotdirs in dir.* and/or include symlinks in dir.*?

Comment: consider if you really need to search `dir.*/*`, maybe just `.` would be appropriate? `find` will (by default) act recursively

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I don't need symlinks in find results.

Comment: @jasonwryan Thank for your answer, I use following code: `find dir.*/. ! -name . -prune -name '*' -exec grep -l "content" {} \; | xargs rm -f`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `find` itself perform the recursion. Also, don't use `xargs`: its input format is not compatible with the output format of `find`. If you have GNU find or FreeBSD/NetBSD/OSX find, it has everything you need built in.

```
find dir.* -mindepth 2 -type f -exec grep -q "content" {} \; -delete
```

Comment: In the rare case that `find` might not suffice, you can use `-print0` and `--null`, respectively: `find somedir -somefilters ... -print0 | xargs --null someexec`. I am not sure about the differences between GNU and POSIX commands, though.